# Angular ng-options track by issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a data set of objects that I'm displaying using ng-options. I'm binding the objects ID value to the  value using `track by`

Currently, the data values are being included but they're being displayed with commas. For example...

```
$scope.items = [
   {ID: '2012', Title: 'Chicago'},
   {ID: '2013', Title: 'New York'},
   {ID: '2014', Title: 'Washington'},
];

<select ng-options="item.Title for item in items track by item.ID">
</select>
```

But this will render...

```
<option value="2,0,1,2" label="Chicago">Chicago</option>
<option value="2,0,1,3" label="New York">New York</option>
```

Why are these commas being added, and how can I remove them?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need track by:

```
<select ng-options="i.ID as i.Title for i in items" ng-model="someModel"></select>
```

After rendering you will have:

```
<option value="2012">Chicago</option>
<option value="2013">New York</option>
```

Comment: I noticed that 'select as' and 'track by' do work if trak by tracks an object, while it does not work if we track an attribute (i.e. 'track by obj.value' )

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
<select ng-options="obj.ID as obj.title for obj in items"></select>
```

Track by just helps angular internally with array sorting. See: [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397347/ngoptions-track-by-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItemID" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items">
</select>

Selected ID: {{selectedItemID}}
```

Comment: This does not add the ID, it just indexes the option values (e.g. 1, 2, 3)

Comment: It adds the ID in the value= part without commas. Several identical answers posted. You can try the same out as a plunkr in JQueryKing's answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Your way**

```
<select ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items" ng-model="someModel"></select>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16826/)

**Alternate way**

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.ID}}">{{item.Title}}</option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/16824/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function MyController($scope){
  $scope.items = [
                  {ID: '2012', Title: 'Chicago'},
                  {ID: '2013', Title: 'New York'},
                  {ID: '2014', Title: 'Washington'},
               ];
  };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">  
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items track by item.ID"></select>
  <br/>{{selectedItem}}
  </body>
  </html>
```

Following should work:--

```
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items track by item.ID"></select>

  {{selectedItem}}
```

Comment: The select box does not change even if the value does, this is an Angular problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be by id then you should use

item.id as item.name for item in items