# Angular ng-option dynamic with ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

> Here I have Items Like this

```
    "items": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Weight",
            "Order": 1,
            "IsCalculated": 0,
            "parameterValues": [
                {
                    "$id": "3",
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Name": "kg",
                    "Weightage": 2,
                    "ParameterId": 0
                },
                {
                    "$id": "4",
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Name": "Tonns",
                    "Weightage": 5,
                    "ParameterId": 0
                },
                {
                    "$id": "5",
                    "Id": 3,
                    "Name": "Brass",
                    "Weightage": 8,
                    "ParameterId": 0
                }
            ],
 {
            "$id": "6",
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Length",
            "Order": 2,
            "IsCalculated": 0,
            "parameterValues": [
                {
                    "$id": "7",
                    "Id": 4,
                    "Name": "CM",
                    "Weightage": 6,
                    "ParameterId": 0
                },
                {
                    "$id": "8",
                    "Id": 5,
                    "Name": "Inch",
                    "Weightage": 9,
                    "ParameterId": 0
                },
                {
                    "$id": "9",
                    "Id": 6,
                    "Name": "km",
                    "Weightage": 7,
                    "ParameterId": 0
                }
            ],
```

Now, With this result bind ng-repeat with main item - like Weight,Length etc
It's look like this Attached image [I need to selected ng-options while edite time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEW5X.jpg) and sub items bind ng-options.

My View Code is Like this
**If any better way please suggest..Thanks..**

```
<div class="mt-10">
                                <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="param in parameter">
                                    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$invalid && !newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$pristine || newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$invalid && submitted, 'has-success' : newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$valid && !newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$pristine || newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$valid && submitted}">
                                        <label for="website">{{param.Name}}: </label>
                                        <select name="{{(param.Name).split(' ').join('_')}}" id="{{(param.Name).split(' ').join('_')}}" ng-model="param.name" ng-options="v as v.Id as v.Name for v in param.parameterValues track by v.Id" ng-change="valuechange(param.Id,param.name)" class="form-control" required>
                                            <option value="">Select  Value </option>
                                        </select>
                                        <p class="help-block">
                                            <span ng-show="newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$invalid && !newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$pristine || newLeadForm.{{param.Name.split(' ').join('_')}}.$>Select {{param.Name}}.</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You are not using `ngOption` correctly. `"v.Id as v.Name for v in param.parameterValues track by v.Id"` instead of `"v as v.Id as v.Name for v in param.parameterValues track by v.Id"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-options track by issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163114/angular-ng-options-track-by-issue)